# Is it possible to extend Redcarpet to auto embed youtube videos from a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, redcarpet

Is it possible to use the [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) Markdown library to automatically embed youtube videos from youtube share links? If so anyone got any ideas on how to go about it? (I'm using Ruby/Rails 3.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it is, you can override the method .to_html, but you probably dont need to even extend it  you could instead do something like this;

```
# my regex is a little rusty
@html = Redcarpet.new(@article.content).to_html
@html = @html.gsub(/\[youtube\s+(.*?)\]/, "....actual html you want in here with youtube id \\1 ")
```

That would replace any instace of `[youtube YOUTUBE_ID]` with your custom html.

Comment: Thanks Adam, tho I was thinking more along the lines of something like auto_html https://github.com/dejan/auto_html where a url is converted rather than a tag. Hence I'm considering using auto_html alongside Redcarpet.

Comment: Great, that would work. You could probably also just change the regex above to something like `@html.gsub(/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(.*?)\s/, "....actual html $1")`

Comment: I just found this while working on something similar. I just wanted to point out that I needed to escape the brackets in my regexp. `/\[youtube\s+(.*?)\]/`